# How can I load a text separately using my modal box?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have created a modal box. Within my modal box there are sub-categories named publication and food. Each sub category is linked to a checkbox that changes color on click; which also checks and unchecked the checkbox. I have also added code which allows the text within the div to be loaded onto the page after the modal box is closed.

I want to be able to only have only the checked categories to be able to load up the information within the div onto the page after the modal box is closed.

Basically, if the user chooses to check publication by clicking it which turns it red, I want only that div to be shown on page after the modal box is closed. (Vice-versa for the other category)

But if the user has checked both sub categories, I would like both the information from the divs to be shown on page after the modal box is closed.

I have tried created new unique ID for both sub categories and divs but for some reason they are not treated separately.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head> 

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Remember to include jQuery :) -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />

</head>

<style>

.onlyThese{
cursor:pointer;
-webkit-user-select: none;  
-moz-user-select: none;     
-ms-user-select: none;      
 user-select: none;           
}




input[type="checkbox"]+label {  color:blue } 

input[type="checkbox"] { display: none }
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {  color:red } 
}

input:focus{
outline: none;   
}




</style>

<body>






<p> <a class="btn" href="#ex5">Sectors </a> </p>
    
<div id="ex5"; class="modal"; style="background-color:white">
    
<div style="float:left;">

<p> <input type="checkbox" id="group1" class="yourCheckbox" checked="checked"> <label for="group1" class="onlyThese">Publication </label> </p>

<div id="myDiv"> blastoise </div>

<p> <input type="checkbox" id="group2" class="yourCheckboxx" checked="checked"> <label for="group2" class="onlyThese">Food </label> </p>

<div id="myDivs"> water </div>
</div>





            
   
<div>
<p style="float:right"> 
<a href="#" rel="modal:close"; class="onlyThese;"> <b>Apply</b> </a> 
</p>    
</div>

</div>


<script>
  

var content = "";
  $('a[href="#ex5"]').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).modal({
        escapeClose: false,
        clickClose: false,
        showClose: false,
      });
     $('#myDiv, #myDivs').hide();
  $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
});
 
 $('.yourCheckbox, .yourCheckboxx').change(function(){
  if($(this).prop("checked")) {
    $('#myDiv, #myDivs').show();
    content = $('#myDiv, #myDivs').html();
  } else {
    $('#myDiv, #myDivs').hide();
    content = "";
  }
});


$('[rel="modal:close"]').on('click',()=>{
     $('.btn').parent().append(content);
    })


      
</script>


</body>

</html>
```

The code should be able to achieve the following:

- -User interacts with modal box named sectors
- - user clicks on a sub category turning it red which also checks the
    checkbox
- -user clicks apply and the information from that specific category div is loaded onto the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) attributes to differentiate between the elements with same events by getting its value from [`$.data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/), consider the following:

```js
var content = "";
$('a[href="#ex5"]').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).modal({
    escapeClose: false,
    clickClose: false,
    showClose: false,
  });
  $('#myDiv, #myDivs').hide();
  $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
});

$('.yourCheckbox, .yourCheckboxx').change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
    $("#" + $(this).data('target')).show();
    content = $("#" + $(this).data('target')).html();
  } else {
    $("#" + $(this).data('target')).hide();
    content = "";
  }
});


$('[rel="modal:close"]').on('click', () => {
  $('.btn').parent().append(content);
})
```

```css
.onlyThese {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label {
  color: blue
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  color: red
}


}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<head>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Remember to include jQuery :) -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- jQuery Modal -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <a class="btn" href="#ex5">Sectors </a>
  </p>
  <div id="ex5" ; class="modal" ; style="background-color:white">

    <div style="float:left;">

      <p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="group1" class="yourCheckbox" data-target="myDiv" checked="checked">
        <label for="group1" class="onlyThese">Publication </label>
      </p>

      <div id="myDiv"> blastoise </div>

      <p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="group2" class="yourCheckboxx" data-target="myDivs" checked="checked">
        <label for="group2" class="onlyThese">Food </label>
      </p>

      <div id="myDivs"> water </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p style="float:right">
        <a href="#" rel="modal:close" ; class="onlyThese;"> <b>Apply</b> </a>
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>


</body>
```